# How to load a bunch of images for deep learning without making my computer freeze

Tags: python-3.x, performance, memory-management, deep-learning, tiff

I have a bunch of tiff images and my goal is to load those images into a numpy array to use it in my keras model in python 3. The problem is that when I turn my images into arrays, my computer froze. I tried first to turn the images into array and save everything in a HDF5 format, now I tried to save only 1000 images and then I used the gc.collect() function to free some memory and then I did this same procedure until there was no images left, but it did not work as well.

So I would like to know an efficient way to get those images into my model. I have about 50.000 images in here. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a Tensorflow data pipeline to load and use images efficiently. Here is an example script that may be useful to you. Assu

```
files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('./*.tiff') # need to change path to point image directory
images = files.map(lambda f: tf.io.read_file(f))
images = images.map(lambda image: tf.io.decode_jpeg(image))
```

#### If you want to do any preprocessing, the following might help you.

```
images = images.map(lambda image: tf.cast(tf.image.resize(image, (128, 128)), tf.uint8))
images = images.map(lambda image: tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255)
```

#### you might need to shuffle, repeat, batch the dataset

For more information, please take a look at tf.data page in [Tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?version=nightly)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it did not work, my tensor after the decode_jpeg is <MapDataset shapes: (None, None, None), types: tf.uint8>. I think that it might not have worked because tensorflow does not support tiff images.